# How to Unit Test a method that has fileName as a Parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have the following method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Customer> GetStuff(string fileName,int filterValue)
```

How would you unit test this? Obviously, my problem is with the `fileName` parameter.

Thank you!

Comment: I did not get your questions. Whats stopping you from passing a dummy file name as an argument?

Comment: I don't know why it should be obvious to us that your problem is with the `fileName` parameter. There is nothing special about the `fileName` which will lead me to believe that you have a problem, so why is it a problem for you?

Comment: @zenwalker at some method I read data from a certain file, and do some processing, please let me know how I can do that without passing fileName as argument

Comment: @Lirik because to write unit test, we need not to depend on another external resource like file, so I was asking how we can resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make another answer-attempt: I guess theJollySin hit the problem but did not explain enough (IMHO)

You seem to take the `fileName` and hit the systems file-system in your `GetStuff` method. And that is the problem if you want to unit-test it.
You have to push the things you do with the file-system (opening/creating/readin files, etc.) into a interface or something and then mock this.
A example might be:

```
public interface IMyFileIO
{
    public byte[] ReadFromFile(int bytes); // whatever
}

public static IEnumerable<Customer> GetStuff(IMyFileIO file, int filterValue)
{
}
```

And then use mocking-frameworks (like for example [MOQ](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart)) to mock `IMyFileIO`:

```
[Test]
public void TestFileIO()
{
   var mock = new Mock<IMyFileIO>();
   mock.Setup(foo => foo.ReadFromFile(2)).Returns(new byte[]{2,3});

   var myResult = MyClass.GetStuff(mock.Object, 10);
   Assert. // <- what you need to check
}
```

Please note that depending on what your are doing, chances are high that there is already a interace/base-class providing the functionality you need (StreamWriter, whatever)

Comment: Thanks Carsten, that's what I was looking for, Yes, I would use streamWriter in my case. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally go for changing a method into something more general like

```
public static IEnumerable<Customer> GetStuff(Stream dataStream,int filterValue)
```

This would give you the ability to use mock stream or MemoryStream instead of FileStream to fetch data and unit test it correctly. Also, I personally suggest making methods as general as they can be (Stream vs. filePath is a good example).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the issue is that the method goes out to the file system to fetch the file?
I would as a precondition to the test actually create a file for your method to get...You may then pass in the newly created file name to your test. 
It becomes an integration test at that point, but it's still valid for testing purposes. It's just not a "pure" unit test

Comment: The test is also re-runnable if you properly handle unique file names per test run. I tend to use GUIDs whenever I need something to be unique. You can clear out the folder on start-up to not accumulate 1000nds of files :-)

Comment: Thanks TGH, yes, it will be sort of integration test, I was trying to avoid that if possible

Comment: Ok,I guess one of the mocking approaches described in the other responses would server you best then :-)

Comment: Yep, I just missed the idea of sending the stream object itself, that was stupid :)